# Не совсем понимаю почему окно ввода не обновляется в PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

col_1 = [
        [sg.B('7', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('8', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('9', size=(4,2), font="bold")],
        [sg.B('4', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('5', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('6', size=(4,2), font="bold")],
        [sg.B('1', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('2', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('3', size=(4,2), font="bold")],
        [sg.B('+/-', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-OPPOSITE-"), sg.B('0', size=(4,2), font="bold"), sg.B('.', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-FLOAT-")]
        ]

col_2 = [
        [sg.B('+', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-PLUS-")],
        [sg.B('-', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-MINUS-")],
        [sg.B('/', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-DIVIDE-")],
        [sg.B('*', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-MULTIPLY-")]
        ]

col_3 = [
        [sg.B('CE', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-CLEAR-")],
        [sg.B('Sqrt', size=(4,2), font="bold", key="-SQRT-")],
        [sg.B('=', size=(4,5), font="bold", key="-EQUALS-")],
        ]

layout = [
        [sg.Input(font=(None, 30), size=(13,1), key="-INPUT-")],
        [sg.Col(col_1), sg.VerticalSeparator(), sg.Col(col_2), sg.Col(col_3)]
        ]

num = (str(i) for i in range(10)) # почему то с кортежом не работает
actions = ''

window = sg.Window("Calculator", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event in num:
        actions += event
        window["-INPUT-"].update(actions)
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, если `num` кортеж, то поле ввода разрешает только 1 раз ввести цифру, но если `num` список, то всё работает как нужно. Я ведь проверяю только вхождение в `num`, а не добавляю туда что-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
print(num)

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

[Program finished]

num = (str(i) for i in range(10))
print(num)

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x73c420d540>

[Program finished]
```

Потому что вы получаете генератор.

```
num = (str(i) for i in range(10))
for value in num:
    print(value)

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

[Program finished]
```